# organization offie 365 SharePoint start page need customize

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

could you please help me too customize offie 365  SharePoint start page. i need to add one session on top of favorite links session .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, customizing start page is not available in the SharePoint Online.

As a workaround, you could set a communication site as the top landing page (SharePoint.aspx) for all users.

Please run below PowerShell as administrator.

```
 Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl <siteUrl>
```

There is [a similar post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/332833/update-sharepoint-start-page-url-across-tenant-in.html) in the Q&A Forum, I suggest you can follow the progress of the post.